# Freya applications menu doesn't respond ("System program problem detected")

Tags: release-freya, slingshot

I installed the latest version of elementary OS from the site. I loved it but am having lots of trouble! Lots of crashes, hanging, and sometimes Applications menu (in the top left) doesn't respond.

I installed it alongside W10. My laptop is MSI Gp60 2pe. Help me, please. I don't wanna break up with this beauty.

[image: Pic]

Comment: My immediate thought is "what did you change?" It's possibly you've changed nothing, but more than likely you've thrown another file-manager on or tried to "enable" desktop icons and it's gone awry. Detailing any action you've taken that includes third-party packages or the command line will probably help people.

Comment: actually I saw this error before doing anything to the system. after that I did everything in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a94MxHHzn1Q , Thank you, i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is a known issue of Ubuntu, inherited by Elementary OS.

The solution to that message is to open a terminal and paste the following line:

```
sudo service apport stop ; sudo sed -i 's/enabled=1/enabled=0/g' /etc/default/apport
```

Then reboot your system and the error message should be gone forever :)

Cheers!

Comment: I'll try it for a while, and then, I'll post the result. THANK You.

Comment: Can you explain what is the problem, and what does this command do?

Comment: Yes, the problem is related to this service, "apport", that is meant to be a bug reporter or something like that. The fact is, disregarding the devs intentions, that is an annoying program. The command just disable permanently this "bug report" feature from ubuntu and derivatives (as elementary). Additionally, even if the thing is working, the information that is needed to fill up a form is not user oriented, so it's way better if you just fill a bug in launchpad manually. No feature is loss with this command, you just disable the program that "reports" the errors (to the users).